# JOSSO's <ignore-url-patterns> example needed

Tags: josso

Just wondering if anyone could show me an example of how the  works with JOSSO's partner-app in joss-agent-config.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this today.  To set URL patterns for the JOSSO ignore-url-patterns tag you need to use a tag from another namespace:

<agent:partner-app context="/" id="Liferay">
   <agent:ignore-url-patterns>
      <s:value>*.css</s:value>
      <s:value>*.js</s:value>
      <s:value>*.gif</s:value>
      <s:value>*.jpg</s:value>
      <s:value>*.png</s:value>
   </agent:ignore-url-patterns>
</agent:partner-app>

This assumes that you have xmlns:agent="urn:org:josso:agent:core" and xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans".

The XSD for the ignore-url-patterns uses the "##other" scope so it must be a tag from another namespace.  I've used spring's <value /> tag because it is a simple container for a string and will work great for holding the various url patterns that you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <configuration>
        <agent:agent-configuration>
            <!-- ============================================================================= -->
            <!--                                                                               -->
            <!-- JOSSO Parnter application definicions :                                       -->
            <!--                                                                               -->
            <!-- Configure all web applications that should be a josso partner application     -->
            <!-- within this server.                                                           -->
            <!-- For each partner application you have to define the proper web-context.      -->
            <!-- ============================================================================= -->
            <agent:partner-apps>
               <agent:partner-app id="AdminApp" context="/admin"/>
               <agent:partner-app id="HOME" context="/home" >
                   <ignore-web-resource-collections>public-resources,img-resources</ignore-web-resource-collections>
               </agent:partner-app>
                <agent:partner-app id="EmployeeApp" context="/emp"/>
                <agent:partner-app id="AuditApp" context="/audit"/>
            </agent:partner-apps>
        </agent:agent-configuration>
```